# iOS native code compile error, use of undeclared identifier 'threadStateData', expanded from macro 'CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG'

Tags: ios, codenameone

I am trying to implement callback from native iOS code for AdMob, here is my code,
com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_NativeInterstitialAdsInterfaceImpl.h:

```
#include "CodenameOne_GLViewController.h"
#include "com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_WordsSynonyms.h"
```

com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_NativeInterstitialAdsInterfaceImpl.m:

```
#import "com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_NativeInterstitialAdsInterfaceImpl.h"

- (void) interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_WordsSynonyms_onInterstitialClosed__(CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG);
}
```

but I am getting compile error that refers to definition of CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG:

```
/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build6871177334585892440xxx/dist/WordsSynonyms-src/com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_NativeInterstitialAdsInterfaceImpl.m:59:78: error: use of undeclared identifier 'threadStateData'
        com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_WordsSynonyms_onInterstitialClosed__(CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG);
                                                                                    ^
In file included from /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build6871177334585892440xxx/dist/WordsSynonyms-src/com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_NativeInterstitialAdsInterfaceImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build6871177334585892440xxx/dist/WordsSynonyms-src/WordsSynonyms-Prefix.pch:18:
/var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build6871177334585892440xxx/dist/WordsSynonyms-src/cn1_globals.h:781:42: note: expanded from macro 'CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG'
#define CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG threadStateData
                                         ^
```

any ideas how to fix that ?

interesting that following code (different macro) in the same .m file doesn't trigger an error:

```
- (void) interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {  
    com_manyukhin_cerebrate_words_synonyms_WordsSynonyms_onInterstitialFaliedToLoad___int(CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_ARG -1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are defined as such:

```
#define CODENAME_ONE_THREAD_STATE struct ThreadLocalData* threadStateData

#define CN1_THREAD_STATE_SINGLE_ARG CODENAME_ONE_THREAD_STATE
#define CN1_THREAD_STATE_MULTI_ARG CODENAME_ONE_THREAD_STATE,
#define CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_ARG threadStateData,
#define CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG threadStateData
#define CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_ARG getThreadLocalData(),
#define CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG getThreadLocalData()
```

So you need to use `CN1_THREAD_GET_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG`. I'm not sure why that wouldn't fail in the same file. It might fail once you fix this call.

Comment: that's helped, compiled successfully, thanks ! but please note that I took the code sample from here: [Advanced Topics/Under the Hood](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html), there is `CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG` (without `_GET`) in callback example, the same [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-ios-code-callbacks.html)

Comment: Thanks. It's what we use in our code which always passes the variable so the method declarations include that variable. I'll fix that. Notice that you can also fix that in the wiki yourself: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/wiki/Advanced-Topics-Under-The-Hood